# Laravel Intervention Image сжатие для png

Tags: laravel, изображения, png, compression

Использую  Intervention/Image для изменения размера и сжатия изображений. проблема заключается в следующем.
при сохранении в png изображение не сжимается . устанавливал качество и от 0-100 и 0-9 бесполезно.
кто сталкивался с такой ситуацией?

```
public static function resizeImage($srcFile, $dstFile, $width, $height, $quality, $sztype, $format = false)
    {

        $a = explode(".", $dstFile);
        $ext = array_pop($a);
        if ($format) {
            $ext = $format;
        }
        $imgFile = Image::make($srcFile);
        $imgFile->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) use ($sztype) {
            if ($sztype == 2) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            }
          
        })->save($dstFile, $quality,  $ext);
        $imgFile->destroy();
    }
```

Comment: качество (необязательно)
Опционально определите качество изображения. Он нормализован для всех типов файлов в диапазоне от 0(низкое качество, маленький файл) до 100(наилучшее качество, большой файл). Качество применяется только в том случае, если вы кодируете формат JPG, поскольку сжатие PNG выполняется без потерь и не влияет на качество изображения. Значение по умолчанию равно 90

Comment: Читайте документацию о модуле, который используете

Comment: понял принял. спасибо